# How can I force JRE to use NTLM authentication?

Tags: java, applet, kerberos, ntlm

We have a 3rd party java applet that seems to be trying to use kerberos authentication by default. We believe it is responsible for timeouts and other issues. We don't use kerberos in our organization. We're not a java shop, but according to what we've discovered through google searches, we can set the 'http.auth.preference' setting to 'NTLM' on the command line if we're running a java application. But how do we set that for our java applet? Setting it through a `<PARAM>` tag doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I wonder what [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480475.aspx) has to say on the subject of "NTLM" vs "Kerberos". Also, I don't know that you can due to the security sandbox.

Comment: Which parameters did you try? Did you set it to http.auth.preference="basic"? Also do you use a jnlp file to start  your applet? Other than that 'param' is the only way...

Comment: We tried using a param like `<param name="http.auth.preference" value="NTLM"></param>` but it seemed to have no effect. Ultimately we found we could add the command line argument in the java control panel. The downside is it affects every applet.

Comment: Usually login configuration is stored (for example inside plugins .jar, .jar is like .zip) in a login.conf file. You may try to correct it, to use only NtLogonModule and force plugin to use your config, by switch -Djava.security.auth.login.config. Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jgss/tutorials/LoginConfigFile.html